# How can I capture error in admin files?

Tags: plugins

My WP always failed when upgrade plugins, I traced it and found it is something about disk io, permission etc. But the problem is it just returns a 500 error without any specific information. 
I traced it in code and can locate the line of code that gives the exception, but I cannot capture the error. I can put wp_send_json_error before the line to verify it. But try/catch doesn't work, I could not find a way to capture the exception and send the exception info back.

Any idea? thanks

Comment: Try looking in the server logs, or in a separate PHP error log if you have one.

Comment: Or think about what that line of code is trying to do, and try reproducing that or investigating it manually. Which line?